# A "mountain sense water"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

So I am doing a camp for vision impaired kids where I play movies for them with audio descriptions on. The other day I played the animated film *Hotel Transylvania 2*. I asked in a different post about a line from the film description, and here is another question.

Kids asked me what a "mountain sense water" is, because there is a line in the description that sounds like "Transforming into a bat, the vampire twirls over the surface of a *mountain sense water*, flying." I know "mountain sense water" is probably not what it is, but I just can't make out what it really says. The scene is Dracula follows Mavis, both in bat forms, plunging from their hotel tower, and soars over the surface of a lake at the foot of a mountain. Does a lake in foothills have a name that I am not aware of?

The audio clip can be found [here](https://clyp.it/35refipf).

Comment: Sounds more like "_sends water flying_"

Comment: I agree, it sounds like "the surface of a mountain and sends water flying." Cool, I never heard a clip like that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...the vampire twirls over the **surface of a moat and sends water flying.**

The "lake at the foot of a mountain" is the [*moat*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moat) in this case:

> Definition of moat
>   1 :a deep and wide trench around the rampart of a fortified place (such as a castle) that is usually filled with water *The moat can be crossed by a drawbridge.*
>   2 :a channel resembling a moat (as about a seamount or for confinement of animals in a zoo) *A Bengal tiger stared at me from across the moat.*

Since a moat is usually filled with water, it would make sense for water to go flying, and a trench or channel filled with water has a surface one could fly over.

Comment: '**Moat**' actually makes sense, given that Dracula stays in a castle, and castles have moats around them